# All new builds from TestFlight Suddenly started crashing on launch and with no Crash Logs on Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, testflight, xcode13

Getting a crash on launch since the night of 8th Dec 2021 for all processed builds from TestFlight. Also when run locally on the device, build runs without any crash for both release/develop schemes.

Only devices using iOS version 15 were working fine without any crash issue.

When installed from TestFlight on devices using iOS13 and iOS14 versions, this issue can be reproduced.

```
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Note:
EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing
Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_concurrency.dylib
"/usr/lib/libswift_Concurrency.dylib' (no such file)
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)
(no such file)
```

Also, an email was received regarding distribution on TestFlight: ITMS-90863: Apple silicon Macs support issue.

For which, I had disabled that already from **Pricing and Availability** -> and Unchecked *Make this app available*. But Still, the same crash issue was observerd.

Answer (score 1):

Tried some steps after searching online.

[https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696197][1]

> Finally, Issue got resolved after installing **XCode 13.2 RC**, and Distributing a new build from this XCode version solves the issue.

Hope it will also help other people who might be facing the same issue.

Now **Xcode 13.2.1** version is available to download

Comment: So, should we resubmit our apps to App Store again? our already published apps have the same issue. what should we do?

Comment: Just for the new version of your existing App that you will upload you can upload from 13.2RC or newer Xcode versions.

Comment: Important note, it still crashes on iOS12 if you include any libConcurrency code _anywhere_, even after the Xcode 13.2.1 fix.

Comment: So have you found any fix for iOS 12

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714795

1. If you are building your app with any version of **Xcode 13** and submit these builds to the App Store, your app downloaded from the App Store will crash with a missing library error when run on **iOS 9 - 12.1**. You can **avoid this crash by disabling bitcode** in your app's build settings, rebuilding your app, and submitting an update to the App Store. In general, you are able to build and test your app on these iOS versions directly from Xcode without being affected.
2. If you are building your app with **Xcode 14 or Xcode 14.0.1**, your app will crash on older OS versions, including while building and testing directly from Xcode, as well as after submitting the app to the App Store. The OS versions affected include **iOS 11 - 12.1, macOS 10.13 - 10.14.3, as well as watchOS and tvOS versions** from the same time frame. To work around the crash when building with Xcode 14, **add -Wl,-weak-lswiftCoreGraphics (substituting other library names for swiftCoreGraphics if appropriate for your crash)** to the Other Linker Flags build setting.

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same problem only on devices using iOS 12 (run from xcode & install via testflight) - the solution was to use an older Xcode.

We were using Xcode 13.2.1, and the one that worked was **12.5**, but didn’t  tried any other version in between.

**LE: The issue is fixed on Xcode 13.3**